# why in dijkstra shortest path algorithm, later determined nodes always have longer shortest distances than earlier determined nodes

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I understand that in each step, a new node is moved from the unexplored set to explored set. this node u is determined by minimizing d(s,v) + l(v,u), where v is a node in explored set. I understand d(s,u) > d(s,v) but don't understand why d(s,u) is larger than d(s,v_i) of any v_i in explored set. s here represents the source, and d(s,u) is the shortest distance from s to u. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but don't understand why d(s,u) is larger than d(s,v_i) of any v_i in
>   explored set

This is an inductive property.

Base: `d(s,s) = 0`, and for all other nodes, `d(s,u) >= 0`

Hypothesis, in the i'th step, for each `u` in explored, `v` in unexplored, d(s,u) <= d(s,v).

Let's look on step `i+1`, and let `x` be the chosen node in this step.

From induction hypothesis, for each `u` in explored, `d(s,u) <= d(s,x)`. For each other node `v` in unexplored - if `d(s,v)` wasn't modified in this step, we are done by induction hypothesis from `i`'th step, and since `d(s,x)` is minimal in unexplored, `d(s,x) <= d(s,v)` as well.

If `d(s,v)` was modified, then `d(s,v) = d(s,x) + l(x,v) >= d(s,x)`, and thus `d(s,u) <= d(s,x) <= d(s,v)`.

And in any case, after step `i+1`, for each `u` in `explored_i U {x} = explored_{i+1}` and `v` in `unexplored_i \ {x} = unexplored_{i+1}`, `d(s,u) <= d(s,v)`.

QED.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at some of the many youtube demonstrations of Dijkstra? 
This [animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GT5hYzjNoo) is quite good.

Comment: yes I know how the algorithm works. I just don't get the point that a later determined nodes always gets a high distance value. I don't know how to prove this

Answer (score 1):

If d(s,u) < d(s,v_i) for any v_i, then v_i would have been added first since you always pick the smallest achievable distance.

Comment: It's not enough for a formal proof. It would have been if `d(s,v_i)` was constant. but it's changing every step. You need to show that the changed `d(s,v_i)` (in unexplored) does not violate the property for already explored nodes/

Comment: @amit I'm aware this isn't a proof, but this is the substantial idea you need to make one. The algorithm works because the distances of added vertices are monotonously increasing as a function of rounds, which is why it only works on graphs where you can guarantee that property. That also holds, for example, for graphs with negative edge weights, as long as all of them belong to edges leaving the start node.